# form_invalid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

Tags: python, django, authentication

Hi how are I having a problem with my django user authentication since I am using AbstractBaseUser

Model

```
from Apps.grupo.models import Grupo
from Apps.empresa_area.models import Empresa_area
from Apps.archivos.models import Archivos
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    Group,
    )


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Usuuario tiene email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("usuario debe tener contraseña")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email =self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff  = is_staff
        user_obj.admin  = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True,
                is_admin=True,
        )
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email  = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    saludo = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    grupo = models.ForeignKey(Grupo,  null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    archivo = models.ForeignKey(Archivos, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fec_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    empresa_area_id = models.ForeignKey(Empresa_area, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cargo = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FILES = []

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('user')
        verbose_name_plural = ('users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email


    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

In this model is giving the permissions to validate me by email also I have in this view where user authentication is generated

view

```
from django.contrib.auth import (
    get_user_model,
    authenticate,
    login,
    logout,
    )
from django.views.generic import CreateView, FormView
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import Login

User = get_user_model()


class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = Login
    succes_url = '/'
    template_name = 'Login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        request = self.request
        next_post = request.POST.get('next')
        next_ =     request.GET.get('next')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            try:
                del request.session['email']
            except:
                pass
        return super(LoginView, self).form_invalid()
```

It is validating but it is generating the following error

form_invalid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

Comment: Are you sure that you want to call `form_invalid` and not `form_valid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `form` parameter to the super class call to `form_invalid` i.e

```
return super(LoginView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Why are you using `form_invalid` and not `form_valid`?